# How do I change Visual Studios method autocompleter to use curly brakets instead of lambda?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete

In Visual Studion 2017 Pro, whenever I override a method in a C# child class, I type `override`<kbd>space</kbd>, then use the first couple letters and IntelliSense to select the method I want to override.

This inserts the rest of the method signature and a call to the base method, but uses an expression body for the method (lambda):

```
public override string ToString() => base.ToString();
```

Instead of a block body (curly brackets):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return base.ToString();
}
```

This makes overriding methods tedious. I only override the method if I am going to change what the method does, which almost always requires it to be in a block body to be legible (especially if calling the base method).

Note: Some settings were defaulted by my organization when installing VS2017, that probably set this for single line methods, which the override method will always initially be.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio that controls this behavior?

Comment: I believe that's just the keyboard shortcut for it. I only ever manually type out everything (which is awful sometimes) so I have never run into the issue. There may be something in `Tools > Options` about it , however.

Comment: @Symon there is a shortcut for the Quick Action (Alt+Enter, Enter(to select the first option)) to convert back and forth, which is handy. But, I'd rather it just autocomplete to the format I want. It used to in older versions of VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you're looking for can be found under the Code Style settings for C#.

You can navigate to the setting like so:

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style`

You are then looking for the setting description 'Use expession body for methods'. It is likely to currently be `'When possible'` or `'When on single line'`, but changing this setting to `'Never'` should result in the desired behavior.